# Wann soll man "doch" benutzen?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, semantics

If I say:

> Ich war dagagen, für dich zu stimmen als du mich angerufen hast, und mich doch überzeugt hast.

to express:

> I was against voting for you when you called me and convinced me otherwise.

is that correct? Or must I say:

> Ich war dagagen, für dich zu stimmen als du mich angerufen hast, und mich überzeugt hast, anders zu tun.

Are either or both of these correct? I want to figure out how I could express the "otherwise" part. I think that you can use "doch" in response to someone who assumes the negative, as one uses "nein" when someone assumes the positive. Is that right? When should I use "doch"?

Comment: *und mich überzeugen hast* is wrong grammar. The verb *überzeugen* isn't a modal, so *haben* takes *Partizip II*.

Comment: *Anders zu tun* is nothing you would ever say. A normal sentence would be: *Ich war gegen dich, aber mit deinem Anruf hast du mich überzeugt.*

Answer (score 1):

*Als* denotes simultaneity and attaching it to the first sentence is confusing because I understand it to mean - I was against voting for you when you called. To be clearer, the *als ... anrufen* part should go with *... überzeugen*.

*Doch* comes in to show an affirmation in contrast to the first sentence.

> Ich war dagegen, für dich zu stimmen. Doch du hast mich überzeugt, als du angerufen hast.

Comment: "I was against voting for you when you called" is the exact same translation as intended in the question, so you need to clarify what is confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, both - *anders* or *doch* - are acceptable. You are also correct that *doch* is used for a positive turn after a negative question or intention. To turn positive into negative, *nicht* is used inside a sentence, *nein* is used alone or as start of an answer.

> Ich wollte für Hugo stimmen, als du mich angerufen und überzeugt hast, es nicht zu tun.

Here I found it nicer to avoid using *hast* twice.

Answer (score -1):

I translate places where I would say *doch* with *anyhow*. Even simpler, you can use affirmative do-support. " The nuances are difficult, *Das hast du doch begriffen* (surely, without doubt). As your translation shows, there's no adverb necessary. I'm not sure what you are trying to say with the German.

The first sentence is a garden path sentence, *als* implies simultanity, not sequence of events. You might say *before* instead or construct something with *dann* (first, but then).

*doch* there implies they first didn't want to call you, but then did it anyway.

A dictionary will tell you about *though*. You know that though.

Comment: "Doch" is not the same as "anyhow" or "though" here. It contrasts "dagegen sein" und "überzeugen" - this has nothing to do with the calling part. "Als" is perfectly fine as long as the different parts of the sentence are nested correctly.

Comment: @Annatar I didn't say it was the same. It works anyhow. I was half asleep. "Du hast mich doch überzeugt" works, but "als du mich angerufen und doch überzeugt hast* is stylistically unsound because the subjects of the verbs that you see opposed aren't in agreement, so that *doch* does seem to contrast with a prior action of the closest subject. That confused me when I was half asleep and won't confuse a careful listener, who is willing to tolerate a broken syntax and infer meaning from context. I'm sure someone can draw a pretty syntax tree of the problem, I can't though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: *I'm sure a syntax tree could be drawn by someone, though not by me.*

Comment: "als du mich angerufen und [doch] überzeugt hast" is short for ""als du mich angerufen hast und du mich [doch] überzeugt hast", so there's no problem with agreement.